# Package name not found in Your Uploaded Package section in APO

Tags: sdlc

I am new to the Salesforce Releasing Process and I want to know the correct path for Salesforce SDLC.

I have created and uploaded a Managed Released package. When I log in to APO and go to the Link Your Organization section I give credentials of my packaging Org (in which I developed and uploaded the package). In the Your Uploaded Package Section it says it didn't find the uploaded package. Am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: It's not the answer to your specific question, but I know sometimes when you upload a package, you have to wait a while for Salesforce. For example, when I upload a managed package and then try to install it in a Sandbox for testing a while later i get the same. I've had to wait a couple of hours before.

Comment: yes, i got the solution, i had to wait some time to get the package in APO.

Comment: do you want to provide this as an answer, that will help others in the future.

Comment: @Phil your first comment is a good answer, if you repost it you'll get my vote

Comment: @Phil Hawthorn, i cant see the option for mark as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By popular demand :), here's my first comment as an answer:

It's not the answer to your specific question, but I know sometimes when you upload a package, you have to wait a while for Salesforce. For example, when I upload a managed package and then try to install it in a Sandbox for testing a while later i get the same. I've had to wait a couple of hours before.